# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Exception

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

My app can be started in two ways:

- "Normally" via the launcher
- As an Intent, when the user selects a contact from his address book

The first method works just fine. The main activity opens up, and the user can use the app. The second method however produces the following error/crash:

> Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{de.mystuff.myapp/de.mystuff.myapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "de.mystuff.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/de.mystuff.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.mystuff.myapp-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/de.mystuff.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

In my manifest I have declared the main activity as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And my activity's code looks like this:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")]
  public class MainActivity : Activity, SwipeRefreshLayout.IOnRefreshListener
  {
    AppSettings mAppSettings;

    ContactListViewAdapter mListViewAdapter;

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwiper;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

      // Do some other init stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid to mix up declarative style and manually writing the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")]` is generating a piece of code in the actual used (generated) `AndroidManifest.xml` that looks like:

```xml
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="AndroidApp1" android:name="md5c178831cd46fc53bebc42cf953f78ced.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and your code will be somewhere else. You can find the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` in the output folder `.\obj\Debug\android`.

**Solution:**

You can add your stuff via attributes like:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")]
[IntentFilter(
    new [] { Intent.ActionCall, "android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" },
    Categories = new [] {Intent.CategoryDefault},
    DataScheme = "tel")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, SwipeRefreshLayout.IOnRefreshListener
{
    // ...
}
```

And remove the manual edits from your manifest file. The output will look like:

```xml
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="AndroidApp1" android:name="md5c178831cd46fc53bebc42cf953f78ced.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.Android, I was able to solve this problem by removing activity declaration and setting my package as `ProjectNamespace.ProjectNamespace` in the `AndroidManifest.xml.` I don't know why it worked but it did.

Here is how my `Manifest` file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="CSharpApp.CSharpApp" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/maps_api_key" />
  </application>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```