# Data Logic SDK Integration throws Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I'm trying to do a simple app that **scan a barcode** using  [Datalogic Sdk](https://datalogic.github.io/xamarin/tutorials/decode-listener.html). In the example, they used Xamarin native for android and when I run it, everything work. But When I try to do it in a custom Xamarin Forms app

```
namespace my_project.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "my_project", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IReadListener
    {
        public event EventHandler<ScanEventArgs> OnScan;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public void OnRead(IDecodeResult p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0.BarcodeID);
            Console.WriteLine(p0.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

it crash with this message:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname/md5eedca812c943a42a1dd347cfedc77c45.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5eedca812c943a42a1dd347cfedc77c45.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.companyname-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I thought It was the cause of the Activity implementing the interface, so I try to separate the listener from the action like in this [example](https://github.com/datalogic/xamarin-samples/tree/AddReadListener/DecodeListener/decodelistener)

```
public class ReadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IReadListener
{
    public void OnRead(IDecodeResult decodeResult)
    {
        Log.Debug("", "Text: " + decodeResult.Text + " barcodeID " + decodeResult.BarcodeID);
    }
}
```

But it was still failing: [image]

If someone as some idea on how to solve one of this exception or just another way to integrate this SDK in a Xamarin Forms App?

Thank you.

Comment: are you doing any manual entry in the manifest file?

Comment: if so, then please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081925/unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-exception

Comment: Have made required changes to your question because it was sort of misleading now to answer your question I would suggest you put the stack trace also as that might help understand and pinpoint the problem

Comment: Have you added `<uses-library android:name="com.datalogic.device" android:required="true" />` as said in the [tutorial](https://datalogic.github.io/xamarin/quick-start/#Android%20manifest)?

Comment: That was that! Thank you! I did not check the quickstart part, only tutorial one... I wish I could validate this as an answer but it is a comment sorry.

Comment: @vmagrez I will reply an answer, please help to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `<uses-library android:name="com.datalogic.device" android:required="true" />` to manifest file as said in the [tutorial](https://datalogic.github.io/xamarin/overview#android-manifest).